# Android Admob SDK AdUnitID for Google play release

Tags: android, admob, adsense

I have used Android Admob SDK with android studio.And my test banner ad displayed properly on my app. Here I used Ad Unit ID from [developer document](https://developers.google.com/admob/android/quick-start).

1. Can I use same AdUnitID when I release app on Google play alpha release?
2. Can I use same AdUnitID when I release app on Google play production release?
3. Still I didn't created AdMob account (or) Adsense account. 
   Only I have Google wallet account, created when I register on Google play. 
   Shall I need to create Admob account and also Adsense account? Or Wallet account is enough to credit on my account.
4. I have put smart banner ad on my app, In which basis money will credit to me,either based on impressions or need to touch ad.

Is it any other important point I need to do,before alpha release (or) production release on Google play.

I have pasted my code below for reference.

**MainActivity.java**

```
public class MainActivity extends BaseActivity{

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        AdView eAdView= (AdView) findViewById(R.id.adView);
        AdRequest adRequest = new AdRequest.Builder().build();
        eAdView.loadAd(adRequest);
    }

}
```

**activity_main.xml**

```
<FrameLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:ads="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".MainActivity">

    <com.google.android.gms.ads.AdView
        android:id="@+id/adView"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        ads:adSize="SMART_BANNER"
        ads:adUnitId="@string/banner_ad_unit_id"
        android:layout_marginTop="?attr/actionBarSize"
        />

        ... 

        ...

<FrameLayout>
```

**strings.xml**

```
<string name="banner_ad_unit_id">ca-app-pub-3940256099942544/6300978111</string>
```

Answer (score 0):

You should

1. Create an Admob account
2. Create an Admob AdUnit and get it's Id
3. Use the id from (2) in your app.

Comment: When I try create AdMob account it asks AdSense account... So I need to create AdSense with bank details and money will credit there. Is it right?

Comment: I have created Admob account and got Adunit and its ID.Can I use debug AdUnit ID on Google play alpha release?

Comment: There is no such thing as a debug AdUnitId. You can use all AdUnitIds on alpha and production releases. If you want test ads then you need to add the id for your device as a test id. See https://developers.google.com/admob/android/targeting

Comment: Yes I understand. If I use test AdUnitId,it shows dummy Adview.If I use real AdUnitID(get from AdMob account) will get impression count.so to avoid false count,I need to add device ID.